# Why the window is popup and disappear after running shell script code

Tags: powershell, terminal, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I use windows terminal when i run a shell script code a window is shown and disappeared and this video will explain what i mean
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nlXoe3SYU7OgAhI6N53YnYSOdEtLK7lL/view?usp=sharing

Edit:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello
name="mostafa nasser"
echo $name
$SHELL
```

the code inside .sh file

Comment: Whats inside the script?

Comment: a simple shell script code that printout hello

Comment: #!/bin/bash
echo hello
name="mostafa nasser"
echo $name

Comment: What bash are you running, from WSL?

Comment: i don't know yesterday i start learn shell and the video use it work fine with the instructor

Comment: Any updates? Were you able to fix this?

Comment: just add read at the end of the program when i input 0 it exit

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your .sh script to keep the window open.
Add $SHELL at the end of the .sh script

Comment: so if my .sh named first it must be first$SHELL.sh or first.sh$SHELL

Comment: @user9339240 open first.sh in text editor and add $SHELL after the last line in the file.

Comment: @user9339240 What happens if you run command - bash first.sh

Comment: i get this message : bash : The term 'bash' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ bash FirstShell.sh
Note file name FirstShell.sh

Answer (score 0):

Do this first:

```
$env:PATHEXT += ';.SH'
```

I tried Windows Subsystem for Linux with Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store, but it didn't make any association to .sh.  But this worked for me:

```
bash file.sh
```

Comment: in the top of the powershell?